# Divide every channel of image by weight image in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have an 3 channel image that is basically a composition of weighted patches. After adding all contributions to my sum image, I want to divide it by the weights. Right now, I use the following code:

```
Mat weighted_sum, weights;
// for (Patch p: patches)
//   weighted_sum[loc_p] += w * p
//   weights[loc_p] += w;

vector<Mat> channels(3);
split(weighted_sum, channels);
for (Mat chan: channels) {
    divide(chan, weights, chan);
}
merge(channels, reconstructed);
```

Is there any more efficient solution for dividing all 3 channels of an image by the same 1-channel image?

Comment: does divide method work for 3 channel images? then you could expand your weights matrix to a 3 channel matrix with all 3 channels = weight (e.g. cv::cvtColor GRAY2BGR). But I doubt it to be much faster because if will basically do the same: divide each channel pixel value by a single float number... but maybe worth a try because of SSE instructions or other optimizations which might be inside the divide function...

Comment: That would work too, but I'm still copying a lot around. My main concern is, that the 'divide' method makes a copy of the whole image (split into channels). Since it seems like a often occurring problem, I was wondering if I could do it somehow in place (without copying neither the weights nor the image).

Comment: copy of the image isnt necessary if you switch from `divide(chan, weights, chan);` to `divide(chan, weights, destination);` and destination is pre-allocated (e.g. if you process multiple images of the same size you only have to allocate destination memory once). the operation will be: read pixel/channel data from image. divide value. write to memory. No `copy` is necessary in that definition.

Comment: what's the type of your matrices?

Comment: @panmari what type (8U, 32F, 64D) do your matrices `weighted_sum` and `weights` have initially?

Comment: @Micka discard my previous message, it was my mistake, and your methods works ok!

Comment: @Miki but looks slow :D

Comment: @Micka see my comment on the answer below, your method was fastest for me ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested your method against:

1. split - divide - merge, @panmari
2. Linearize matrices, and apply element wise division @Miki
3. Linearize matrices, and apply element wise division (with pointers) @Miki and multiplication instead of division @Micka
4. Make `weights` a 3 channel matrix, and apply `divide` on whole matrices @Micka.

Results (in ms):

```
Size            Method1         Metdhod2        Method3         Method4
[2 x 2]         0.0359212       0.00183271      0.000733086     1.77333
[10 x 10]       0.0117294       0.00293234      0.00109963      0.0051316
[100 x 100]     0.422624        0.241918        0.0751413       0.319625
[1000 x 1000]   20.757          20.3673         7.28284         18.4389
[2000 x 2000]   83.6238         82.942          28.4353         74.2132
```

**NOTES**

- My method works faster, but the speed-up is related to the size of the matrices.
- Method 3 (with pointers) is the fastest
- Method 2 and Method 3 modify the original matrix. If you need not to change original matrix, you need to do a deep copy (`clone()`, see commented lines in code below). With deep copy of the original matrix both methods are slower, but Method 3 is still the fastest.
- Method 4 won't work with `double` matrices, since `cvtColor` doesn't accepts `double`).
- Preallocating matrices for Method 4 is just a small improvement.
- Tested with compiler msvc12 (Visual Studio 2013). With gcc 4.8 Method 4 seems to be faster.

Here the code I used. I'm testing on float matrices, but it's easy to port to other types.

```
    #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


int main()
{
    vector<Size> sizes{Size(2,2), Size(10,10), Size(100,100), Size(1000,1000), Size(2000,2000)};

    cout << "Size \t\tMethod1 \tMetdhod2 \tMethod3 \tMethod4" << endl;

    for (int is = 0; is < sizes.size(); ++is)
    {

        Size sz = sizes[is];
        Mat3f weighted_sum(sz);
        randu(weighted_sum, 0, 200);

        Mat1f weights(sz);
        randu(weights, 0, 10);

        Mat3f ws1 = weighted_sum.clone();
        Mat3f ws2 = weighted_sum.clone();
        Mat3f ws3 = weighted_sum.clone();
        Mat3f ws4 = weighted_sum.clone();



        // Method 1 @parmari
        double tic1 = double(getTickCount());
        Mat3f rec1;

        vector<Mat> channels(3);
        split(ws1, channels);
        for (Mat chan : channels) {
            divide(chan, weights, chan);
        }
        merge(channels, rec1);

        double toc1 = (double(getTickCount() - tic1)) * 1000. / getTickFrequency();

        // Method 2 @Miki
        double tic2 = double(getTickCount());
        Mat3f rec2 = ws2.reshape(3, 1);
        //Mat3f rec2 = ws2.reshape(3, 1).clone(); // To not override original image
        Mat1f ww2 = weights.reshape(1, 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < rec2.cols; ++i)
        {
            double w = ww2(0, i);
            Vec3f& v = rec2(0, i);
            v[0] /= w;
            v[1] /= w;
            v[2] /= w;
        }
        rec2 = rec2.reshape(3, ws2.rows);

        double toc2 = (double(getTickCount() - tic2)) * 1000. / getTickFrequency();


        // Method 3 @Miki (+ @Micka)
        double tic3 = double(getTickCount());
        Mat3f rec3 = ws3.reshape(3, 1);
        //Mat3f rec3 = ws3.reshape(3, 1).clone(); // To not override original image
        Mat1f ww3 = weights.reshape(1, 1);

        Vec3f* prec3 = rec3.ptr<Vec3f>(0);
        float* pww = ww3.ptr<float>(0);

        for (int i = 0; i < rec3.cols; ++i)
        {
            float scale = 1. / (*pww);
            (*prec3)[0] *= scale;
            (*prec3)[1] *= scale;
            (*prec3)[2] *= scale;

            ++prec3; ++pww;
        }
        rec3 = rec3.reshape(3, ws3.rows);

        double toc3 = (double(getTickCount() - tic3)) * 1000. / getTickFrequency();


        // Method 4 @Micka
        double tic4 = double(getTickCount());
        Mat3f rec4;
        Mat3f w3ch4;
        cvtColor(weights, w3ch4, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
        divide(ws4, w3ch4, rec4);

        double toc4 = (double(getTickCount() - tic4)) * 1000. / getTickFrequency();

        cout << sz << " \t" << toc1 << " \t" << toc2 << " \t" << toc3 << " \t" << toc4 <<  endl;

    }

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: might your method even be faster when you compute `float scale = 1/*ppw;` followed by `(*prec3)[0 to 2] *= scale`? Can you try the same test for Method 5, which equals method 4 with preallocated destination matrix and w3ch matrix outside of time measurement (which is feasbile imho in cases where you process a whole video stream or sth), since reshape version doesnt allocate memory at all.

Comment: 1) yeah, a lot! Thanks! 2) I was already trying that, but there isn't much difference. I'll check better and update the answer

Comment: nice answer btw. Would be interesting to analyze different hardware and library settings, too (SSE, tbb, IPP, etc), but I guess in the end the user should test those himself :D

Comment: Thanks for your tests! I recreated your script as performance test (where I also test if they produce the same result). On my machine, Method 4 was the fastest (for large matrices). See https://gist.github.com/panmari/b9654d2f3e47ca7af825

Comment: @Micka preallocating matrices doesn't help much, so I didn't included it in the code. It's wierd, however.

Comment: @panmari can you tell type and size of your matrices?

Comment: @Miki, as in my gist, they're both 32F, size is about 1 MP. I'll test the new code in a sec.

Comment: @panmari ah.. didn't saw the link :D

Comment: @Miki the new method fails: Value of: countNonZero(diff.reshape(1))
  Actual: 72
Expected: 0

Comment: @panmari : do you compile your project with optimizations? If not, "manual" steps (like looping over whole matrix manually) will be slower compared to OpenCV library functions which use optimizations. So in the end, method 2 and 3 will be more compiler dependent than methods 1 and 4, which can be both: good or bad ;)

Comment: @panmari works ok for me. It's equivalent to the old one, just with multiplication for the inverse instead of a division

Comment: @Micka it's compiled with -O3.

Comment: results might differ because of numerical issues (if values/weights are very large and/or very small). Or: does `cv::divide` use double precision? is `1. / floatVal` double precision division assigned to floating point variable (minor numerical error)? too many questions and numerical sources of errors there... would love to work on that but not enough spare time atm :D

Comment: @panmari Yes, numerical imprecisions... order of 10e-6

Comment: @Miki it's not that, I tried with `threshold(diff, diff, 1e-6, 1, THRESH_BINARY);` There are less non-zero values, but even with a threshold of 1e-1 there are still some.

Comment: just curious: which compilers do both of you use? :D

Comment: @Micka msvc12 (Visual Studio 2013)

Comment: @panmari, you're right, there are some errors till 10e-3. Also, it's probably caused by division by zero or something like that. Setting weights random from 1 to 10 seems to solve the issue for me.

Comment: @Miki good call, seems like it was an issue with division close to 0. Updated gist (same link): https://gist.github.com/panmari/b9654d2f3e47ca7af825

Comment: @Micka I'm on gcc 4.8

Comment: added compiler version to the NOTES in the answer, since it's quite relevant. However, @panmari, have you turned up optimization (/O2 for me)?

Comment: @Miki For my results in the gist, I used the 'release' mode in cmake, which leads to compiling the files with -O3.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92224/discussion-between-panmari-and-miki).